# Unable to open ArcGIS Pro notebook from cloned active environment

Tags: arcgis-pro, conda, arcgis-notebook

I have been working in ArcGIS Pro Notebooks from my default active environment (arcgispro-py3).

I wanted to install a new package in this environment, but once in the package manager I have the following warning at the top of the page: "Cannot modify the default python environment. Clone then activate a new environment first."

I cloned the environment and am able to install the package into the cloned environment. However, when I try to start a Notebook from the cloned environment, I get the error: "Failed to load notebook."

I know that some people say failure to load a notebook may have to do with Windows antivirus protections. However, I can open notebooks just fine from my original environment. It's only when I attempt to open it from the cloned environment that I have an issue.

What can I change to get the Notebook to open? Alternatively, what can I do to install new packages in my default environment where notebooks already open?

Comment: What happens is you try converting the notebook to a .py file and then running the code in a Python window in your cloned environment?  https://mljar.com/blog/convert-jupyter-notebook-python/

Comment: Have you logged this with your local ESRI support? There seems to be lots of problems with ArcPro, especially when you upgrade it and then have to clone your environment again. All sorts of unintended things break.

Comment: I'm able to run lines of code within the Python window, but I want the functionality of notebooks

Answer (score 0):

For now, updating from ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3 to 3.1 has solved this issue for me.